# Sending UDP packets from React-Native app

Tags: react-native, udp

I have created a UDP server, and have tested it using the Microsoft UDP tool and it receives a UDP message and executes accordingly.  I am only trying to send a "1" or a "2", but I need to send this to several UDP Servers nearly simultaneously (which is why I cannot wait for a response).  The Microsoft UDP tool has entry for IP Address & Port, then a connect button - then I type a message and hit send.  Pretty simple and extremely fast.

I can find several examples using React-Native-UDP for receiving, but I cannot find a simple example where someone sends something as simple as a "2" from React-Native to a listening UDP Server.

My goal is to cycle through 10 IP address / port combinations, sending a "1" or "2" depending on the circumstance.

I have accomplished this using HTTP Server, but it is much too slow to be useful.

Is this doable using Native-React-UDP?  Will this work for both Android and iOS?

Comment: isn't this an example of sending?
socket.once('listening', function() {
  var buf = toByteArray('excellent!')
  socket.send(buf, 0, buf.length, remotePort, remoteHost, function(err) {
    if (err) throw err

    console.log('message was sent')
  })
})

Comment: I'm looking to accomplish this in React Native...  I can accomplish it in JavaScript, but does that example work in React?  I've read that React does not work well with UDP due to potential security issues, but I know that game engines must use UDP due to the speed of updates?

Comment: @SWM did you manage to fix it? On my terminal it seems to work but when trying it out on testflight it appears not to be sending any UPD requests. Needed for iOS app

Comment: @Samvanbeastlo did you figure this out for your app?

Answer (score 0):

I made it work with react-native-udp. Create a socket and send the udp request. Make sure you have something like 200-500 ms between requests else they may fail.

docu: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-udp

a extra tip: download one of many udp sender / receiver apps on the play and/or appstore to help you debug. Good luck!

```
import dgram from 'react-native-udp'

const socket = dgram.createSocket('udp4')
socket.bind(12345)
socket.once('listening', function() {
  socket.send('Hello World!', undefined, undefined, remotePort, remoteHost, function(err) {
    if (err) throw err

    console.log('Message sent!')
  })
})

socket.on('message', function(msg, rinfo) {
  console.log('Message received', msg)
})
```